# Tensorflow Python: Feed forward network failing on size?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, feed-forward

Could someone look over this code and see what I'm doing wrong? I'm attempting to do the MNIST default but with a Sign Language MNIST from Kaggle. The images are 100x100 and in the directory "SLMNIST/Dataset/(label)/imagexxxx.JPG"
It's all reading fine but for whatever reason I can't get it to fit into the mnist default (after adjusting for the image size difference).

https://gist.github.com/JLeavell/06ff1c946f76d65d06003fb531592a49

Edit: Error: https://gist.github.com/JLeavell/fb24c3912928e607acb561a58cc5fe0a

Comment: Can you give us some error messages and paste the relevant code you expect is causing the issue? Reading through a couple pages of code for a non descript error isn't likely to get a response.

Comment: Yep! Adding in another gist of the full trace. The error is specified at the bottom. It's in a jupyter notebook so it might look funky, but as far as I know the error is the same regardless